# Validating with Caliburn.Micro

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

Is there a way to validate a textbox input (using Regex) in a wpf application using Caliburn.Micro?

Thanks

Comment: There's http://www.lyquidity.com/devblog/?p=71

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest using an attribute-based approach.  Have a look at this article:

[Validation in WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/97564/Attributes-based-Validation-in-a-WPF-MVVM-Applicat)

The approach here is basically:

Inherit from a validation viewmodel base-class.  This, in turn, could inherit from the Caliburn Screen/Conductor/etc base-classes quite happily

Once this is done all you need to is attribute up the properties you want to validate.  This fits in really nicely with the CM approach.

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a small plugin for CM to enable fluent builder-style validation. Feel free to use it: https://github.com/AIexandr/Caliburn.Micro.Validation